# In Scala, how would I take a Spark RDD, and output to different files, grouped by the values of a column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

If there was a Spark RDD like such:

```
id  | data
----------
1   | "a"
1   | "b"
2   | "c"
3   | "d"
```

How could I output this to separate json textfiles, grouped based on the id? Such that part-0000-1.json would contain rows "a" and "b", part-0000-2.json contains "c", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.write.partitionBy("col").json(<path_to_file>)
```

is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've seen this solution before, but the `partionBy()` creates a new directory where it collects separate files, whereas I'm looking to collect all rows to a single file. I hope that clarifies

Comment: Thanks for putting me back on the right track. I've since found the solution and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thebluephantom, I was able to understand what was going wrong.

I was fundamentally misunderstanding Spark. When I was initially doing `df.write.partitionBy("col").json(<path_to_file>)` as @thebluephantom suggested, I was confused as to why my output was split into many different files.

I have since added `.repartition(1)` to collect all data into a single node, and *then* `partitionBy("col")` to split the data in here to multiple file outputs. My final code is:

```
latestUniqueComments
  .repartition(1)
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy("_manual_file_id")
  .format("json")
  .save(outputFile)
```